# Variable did not get value when it was in JavaScript local function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I tried to do some calculations as following.

The weight value should subtract its value from score. But when I was doing this I got "undefined" as the `score` variable output. What is the reason? Did I handle the variable declarations correctly?

```
var score = 10;

var scoresFunc = function (weight) {
    console.log(score);
    var finalScore = score - weight;
    score = score - finalScore;
    var scoreForStartingDate = $('#scoreForStartingDate').val();
    var scoreForDuration = $('#scoreForDuration').val();
    var scoreForProjects = $('#scoreForProjects').val();

    var score = score - parseInt(weight);
    var a = '';
    for (i = 1; scores >= i; i++) {
        a += "<option value='" + i + "'>" + i + "</option>";
    }
    return a;
};
```

Comment: where you are getting undefined?

Comment: mention the error completely instead of saying just `undefined`

Comment: See the console log. score variable gave undefined

Comment: @GRTZ: Did you call the funtion? Defining a function returns nothing (undefined) so it will ***ALWAYS*** print undefined after you define a function!

Comment: `for( i = 1; scores >= i` ... scores is not defined at this point, which is different than undefined, and causes a Reference Error. Define scores. Perhaps you meant var scores = score - parseInt(weight);. In which case you will still get weight * -1 because at that point score is always 0. It is unclear what exactly you are getting at with this question, or what the purpose of this code was.

Comment: If this is what I think this is I've voted to close but this is the third question this week asking why the console prints undefined when that's normal behavior. I think it may be useful to actually have an answer for this.

Comment: @slebetman - Okay, I will post an answer as to why it is undefined. But the function fails to execute following the console log.

Comment: @GRTZ: To be clear, in your code example above you don't show us how you're calling the function. If you don't call the function then it's perfectly normal to see that undefined. There's nothing wrong.

Comment: what are you expecting from the above code? And the two things i noticed are 1.var score = score - parseInt(weight);--> no need of declaring the variable again. 2. for (i = 1; scores >= i; i++) {  --> you didn't define the variable score and you are using  it

Answer (score 5):

The reason you see undefined logged for console.log(score) is because of something called ***[variable hoisting<sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)***.

```
var score = 10;
var scoresFunc = function (weight) {
    console.log(score);
    var score = score - weight;
};
```

This is a condensed version of the shown function. However, as a result of hoisting, it is actually this

```
var score = 10;
var scoresFunc = function (weight) {
    var score;
    console.log(score);
    score = score - weight;
};
```

Which should hopefully clear up why you log `undefined`.

Comment: No I want get value 10 into the function. thats why i put like that

Comment: @GRTZ - Use separate variable names. You are overwriting the variable in the function scope.

Answer (score 1):

in here: `var score = score - parseInt(weight);`
you redefine variable score, so maybe it's caused the first operator become undefined...

also watch out for the loop, you used scores instead of score

Comment: No I want get value 10 into the function. thats why i put like that

Comment: man it was that, and i test it, it worked fine,... just find that line, and remove `var`, when you redefine the same variable you casue local variable to refer to that object. so they become undefined, remove the `var` and every thing will be ok. write this instead: `score = score - parseInt(weight);`

Answer (score 1):

The `var score` you have inside your function is likely messing things up.  Remember that ALL `var` definitions are automatically hoisted to the very top of their function scope.  That means your function is the equivalent of this:

```
var scoresFunc = function (weight) {
    var score, scoreForStartingDate, scoreForDuration, scoreForProjects, a;
    console.log(score);
    var finalScore = score - weight;
    score = score - finalScore;
    scoreForStartingDate = $('#scoreForStartingDate').val();
    scoreForDuration = $('#scoreForDuration').val();
    scoreForProjects = $('#scoreForProjects').val();

    score = score - parseInt(weight);
    a = '';
    for (i = 1; scores >= i; i++) {
        a += "<option value='" + i + "'>" + i + "</option>";
    }
    return a;
};
```

So, because you have a `var score` inside the function, then that overrides the global name within this scope and any references to `score` will use the local variable.

Therefore, this line:

```
score = score - parseInt(weight);
```

will be this:

```
score = undefined - parseInt(weight);
```

Which obviously does not work.

---

I don't know exactly what you're trying to accomplish in this function.  Perhaps you just need to remove the `var` in this line:

```
var score = score - parseInt(weight);
```

so that you are operating on the higher scoped `score` variable, not the local variable.

Answer (score 0):

use `parseFloat` or  `parseInt` like

```
var finalScore = Number(parseFloat(score) - parseFloat(weight));
```